# how confiugre tmux to display current language on status bar

Tags: tmux

As I am using multiple input languages and frequently switch between them, I'd like to see the currently selected language. Is it something that can be configured? if not should I modify the code or write a tmux pluging for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to show current language you need install `xkb-switch` and also need to have small interval e.g. `status-interval 1`

```
set -g status-right "#(xkb-switch)"
```

Answer (score 4):

For macOS add below to `~/.tmux.conf`:

```
set -g status-right "#(defaults read ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.HIToolbox.plist AppleCurrentKeyboardLayoutInputSourceID | awk -F. '{print $4}')"
set -g status-interval 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this adding it to your `.tmux.conf`:

```
set -g status-right "#(setxkbmap -print | awk -F'+' '/xkb_symbols/ {print $2}')"
```

Comment: thanks but this finds the first language instead of current language, e.g. if I have 3 languages and currently the keyboard is switched to the second language, this would show me the first one while I need the second one

Comment: It is working from me in Ubuntu 14.04. Which os do you have?

Comment: I am on Fedora 23 with tmux 2.0, I have a Ubuntu machine also but I have not checked it there yet.

Answer (score 1):

Just add to `.tmux.conf`

```
wg_lang="#{?#(xset -q | grep LED | cut -c63),[RU],[EN]}"

set -g status-right "$wg_lang"
```